# How to do negative binomial regression with the rms package in R?

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, rms

How can I use the `rms` package in R to execute a negative binomial regression?

With the `MASS` package, I use the `glm.nb` function, but I am trying to switch to the `rms` package because I sometimes get weird errors when bootstrapping with `glm.nb` and some other functions. But I cannot figure out how to do a negative binomial regression with the `rms` package.

Here is sample code of what I would like to do (copied from the `rms::Glm` function documentation):

```
library(rms)
## Dobson (1990) Page 93: Randomized Controlled Trial :
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
f <- Glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family=poisson())

f
anova(f)
summary(f, outcome=c('1','2','3'), treatment=c('1','2','3'))
```

So, instead of using `family=poisson()`, I would like to use something like `family=negative.binomial()`, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

In the documentation for `family {stats}`, I found this note in the "See also" section:

```
For binomial coefficients, choose; the binomial and negative binomial distributions, Binomial, and NegBinomial.
```

But even after clicking the link for NegBinomial, I cannot make any sense of this.

I would appreciate any help on how to use the `rms` package in R to execute a negative binomial regression.

Comment: OK; I have reposted this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686004/how-to-do-negative-binomial-regression-with-the-rms-package-in-r